# How Can I create an image with python PIL where there are two colors?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Here is an example of the output I want to generate. I'm able to create an image with one color, but I don't have idea of how can use two colors, and how to color  only certain parts of the image [image: image size].

Comment: Please provide some code for us. What have you done so far??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way. I created two image with two different colors, and then paste them in another one image.

```
width = 400 
height = 300 
img = Image.new( mode = "RGB", size = (width, height), color = (209, 123, 193) )
#First IMG
 
img2 = Image.new( mode = "RGB", size = (width, height + 400), color = (255, 255, 255) ) 
#Second IMG

img3 = Image.new('RGB', (img.width, img.height + img2.height)) img3.paste(img, (0, 0)) img3.paste(img2, (img.width, 0)) 
#IMG + IMG2
```

I got my result.